# Move and Jump animation for UIImageView : Swift 4

Tags: swift, animation

I need to make my image jump and move down with animation. I am using sprites to show the jump animation. But, when I try to combine it with move down animation, it does not work. I am trying it on click of a button. Below is my code.

My animation works properly for second click but for first click it just jumps at its current location and at second click it jumps and moves down. I am trying to make it jump and move down at first button click.

```
@IBAction func targetTouchAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let images: [UIImage] = (1...10).map { return UIImage(named: "Jump_\($0)")! }
        self.jackImage.frame.origin.y = self.jackImage.frame.origin.y + 100.0
        self.jackImage.animationImages = images
        self.jackImage.animationDuration = 2.0
        self.jackImage.animationRepeatCount = 1
        self.jackImage.startAnimating()
    }
```

I am trying this from last two three hours but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing 2 different types of animation. Don't do that. Using the `animationImages` property of a `UIImageView` is separate from using `UIView` animation methods like `UIView.animate(duration:animations:)`

Get rid of that `UIView` animation wrapper, and just specify the animation images and other settings for your image view:

```
@IBAction func targetTouchAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let jumpImages = ["Jump_1","Jump_2","Jump_3","Jump_4","Jump_5","Jump_6","Jump_7","Jump_8","Jump_9","Jump_10"]
    var images = [UIImage]()
    for image in jumpImages{
        images.append(UIImage(named: image)!)
    }
    self.imageView.frame.origin.y = self.imageView.frame.origin.y + 100.0
    self.imageView.animationImages = images
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 2.0
    self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    self.imageView.startAnimating()
}
```

Note that loading the array of images into the image view each time you trigger the animation is unnecessary, but it should still work.

I haven't worked with SpriteKit, so I'm not sure how your image view animation will interact with that. (Plus you didn't show that part of your code.)

Also, note that you could create your array of images with 1 line of code, and without using a hard-coded array of filenames:

```
let images: [UIImage] = (1...10).map { return UIImage(named: "Jump_\($0)") }
```

That code creates a sequence from 1 to 10. It then uses the map statement to map that sequence into an array of images by feeding the value into a string, and using that string as the image name in a call to `UIImage(named:)`

Comment: Thanks! That was good information. Though It is still not working. I removed the UIView animation but it still does not work on first click. On first click of button it jumps at same place and on second click it jums and moves down. Not sure why its working properly on second click but not working on first click. I have updated my code as per your suggestion and edited here as well.